# concatenate vectors from two lists by names

Tags: r, list

So I'm heavily simplifying my actual problem, but I am trying to find a way to append values inside vectors from one list, to values in vectors in another list, and do it by name ( assuming the two lists are not ordered).So this is the setup to the problem ( the numbers themselves are arbitrary here):

```
Data1 <- list( c(1),c(2),c(3))
names(Data1) <- c("A", "B","C")

Data2 <- list(c(11), c(12), c(13))
names(Data2) <- c("B","A","C")
```

Now what Im trying to do, is find a way to get a third list - say Data3, so that  calling `Data3[["A"]]` will give me the same result as calling c(1,12):

```
[1] 1 12
```

so `>Data3` should give:

```
[1] 1 12
[2] 2 11
[3] 3 13
```

Essentially im looking to append many values from one list of vectors, to another list of vectors, and do it by names rather than order, if that makes sense. (I did think about trying some loops, but I feel like there should be another way that is simpler)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
nm = names(Data1)
setNames(lapply(nm, function(x){
    c(Data1[[x]], Data2[[x]])
}), nm)
#$A
#[1]  1 12

#$B
#[1]  2 11

#$C
#[1]  3 13
```

Comment: Hey, yeah this worked well, I guess i should work more on understanding the apply methods.

Answer (score 2):

```
list(do.call("cbind", list(Data1, Data2)))
  [,1] [,2]
A 1    11  
B 2    12  
C 3    13
```

If you don't mind your output to be a dataframe:

```
Data3 <- rbind(data.frame(Data1), data.frame(Data2))
```

Then `Data3[["A"]]` will give you:

```
[1]  1 12
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `Map` and arrange the elements of `Data2` in the same order as `Data1` (or vice versa) using names and then concatenate them.

```
Map(c, Data1, Data2[names(Data1)])

#$A
#[1]  1 12

#$B
#[1]  2 11

#$C
#[1]  3 13
```